# Having problems with a For loop not terminating after it's cycled through all the ranges. It runs through them and then gives an error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm writing a macro to copy a bunch of discussion points from our underwriting workbook and paste them into a Word doc for upload to our UWing system. I've managed to write the macro below and it seems to loop through each range successfully, however, when it gets done, an error pops up. Specifically, Run-time error '4198': command failed.

I'm not sure what's causing it, I've tried ending the For loop, but when I do, it stops it after the first pass through the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub PasteToWord_DiscussionPoints()

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
        Dim wordapp As Word.Application
        Dim worddoc As Word.Document
        Dim Rng As Variant
        Dim excRng As Range
        Dim rngarray As Variant
        
        'Create New Word Instance
        Set wordapp = New Word.Application
        wordapp.Visible = True
        wordapp.Activate
        Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.add
        
        'Populate range array with what I want to copy
        rngarray = Array(Sheet1.Range("A5:A23"), Sheet1.Range("A25:A39"), _
                Sheet1.Range("A94:A108"), Sheet1.Range("A128:A132"), _
                Sheet1.Range("A134:A163"), Sheet1.Range("A192"), _
                Sheet1.Range("A394"), Sheet1.Range("A404"), _
                Sheet1.Range("A416"))
        
        'Loop through each range in array copy/paste
        For Each Rng In rngarray
        
            Set excRng = Rng
                excRng.Copy
                'pause to allow Excel to catch up
                Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:05 AM#
                
                With wordapp.Selection
                    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
                End With
                
            wordapp.ActiveDocument.Sections.add
            
            'Go to newly created page
            wordapp.Selection.Goto what:=wdGoToPage, which:=GoToNext
            
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Next
        MsgBox "Huzzah"
     
End Sub
```

Comment: I think 'which:=GoToNext' should be 'which:=wdGoToNext'

Comment: I updated "GoToNext" to "wdGoToNext" and the error still occurs. Excel is highlighting the ".PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText" line as where it says the error is occurring.

Comment: When it errors and highlights the `.PasteSpecial` line, if you wait a few seconds and then try continuing with F5, does it then succeed?

Comment: It will actually copy/paste all items that it needs to and then it errors out. So it does what it needs to do, but ends with an error.

Comment: Place `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after the loop.

Comment: I placed it after the loop and still received the same error, I deleted it completely and still get the same error.

Comment: I can't replicate the error. It worked for me after I placed it after the loop. Well, I also just copied `rng` instead of `excRng` but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Maybe try adding a wait after each step?

Comment: Given my first comment, your code as posted should never have worked - since it does, you may have an issue with Word constants, i.e. try changing the line generating the error to .PasteSpecial DataType:=2 (as the underlying value of wdPasteText is 2)

Comment: I'm completely lost. I tried writing this from scratch in a brand new workbook and now I'm getting the issue of it pasting over itself with 10 second wait times instead of creating a new page and going to the new page. And it's not erroring out anymore. I don't know if it's a system issue, ive tried it on a personal computer and my work computer and it still happens. I just... i don't know